# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>to . An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have the following code:

```
private GolfManagementEntities db = new GolfManagementEntities();

    public class ThanhToan
    {
        public ThanhToan()
        { }
        public Double Total { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }

    public List<ThanhToan> listInvoice(DateTime tuNgay, DateTime denNgay)
    {

       List<ThanhToan> invoice= from i in db.Invoices 
                                where i.Date >= tuNgay && i.Date <= denNgay 
                                group i by i.Date into In 
                                select new ThanhToan { 
                                    date= Convert.ToDateTime(In.Key) , 
                                    Total = Convert.ToDouble(In.Sum(s => s.ExtendedCost))
                               };

       return invoice;

}
```

And I got this error :

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>to . An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

please help me

Answer (score 5):

Your query returns `IQueryable<THanhToan>` but you're trying to return a `List<ThanhToan>`. There's no implicit conversion available (as per the error message) but you can use the [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method to create a list:

```
public List<ThanhToan> ListInvoices(DateTime tuNgay, DateTime denNgay)
{

    var query = from i in db.Invoices 
                where i.Date >= tuNgay && i.Date <= denNgay
                group i by i.Date into g
                select new ThanhToan {
                    date = Convert.ToDateTime(g.Key), 
                    Total = Convert.ToDouble(g.Sum(s => s.ExtendedCost))
                };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

(I've changed your method name to follow .NET naming conventions and make more sense in terms of it returning *multiple* invoices, not just one. Also note how spreading the query over multiple lines makes it *much* easier to read.)