# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Program.Data.View' TO System.linq.iqueryable<Program.Data.View>.

Tags: c#, linq, casting, iqueryable

**Goal/Problem:** I am trying to use the First or FirstOrDefault to only return 1 result from the Database. I'm getting the following error:

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'Program.Data.view' to System.Linq.Iqueryable An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)*

**What I've tried:**
After looking through documentation and many SO articles, I tried different ways of casting, including the code below. Articles such as [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>to . An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188222/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryableto-an-explicit-convers). Most of the articles are going from System.Linq.IQueryable<> to something else, not this direction. Either way casting should be relatively easy, what am I missing?:

```
IQueryable<Program.Data.view> someVariable = db.view.First(m => m.ID == Search_ID);
```

My method signature is:

```
public IQueryable<Program.Data.view> GetDataFromQuery()
```

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working was the following:

```
var someVariable = db.view.Where(m => m.Some_ID == Search_SomeID).GroupBy(x => x.Some_ID).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Column_Two).FirstOrDefault()).AsQueryable().OrderBy(x => x.Column_Three);
```

AKA (format):

```
Where().GroupBy().Select(...OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault()).AsQueryable().OrderBy();
```

Not sure why the others gave me errors but doing it in this order worked
Also, the OrderBy at the very end seems completely unecessary by logic, but I get a System.NotSupportedException error when I don't have it (The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip' ... this happens on .DataBind())

Answer (score 5):

`First()` and similar methods (like `FirstOrDefault()` or `Count()` or `Average()`) does **not** return an `IQueryable<Program.Data.view>` and does not use deferred execution.

`First()` is executed *immediatly* and returns **only one** (well, the *first*) `Program.Data.view`.

So the error message is correct. Change your signature to

```
public Program.Data.view GetDataFromQuery()
```

and the mentioned line to:

```
Program.Data.view someVariable = db.view.First(m => m.ID == Search_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use of method like: `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, `Count()` and something like this, return type of data that you mapped in `Entity-Framework`.

When you work with `Entity-Framework`, Do you know, when `EF` get data from `database`?

Look this sample:

```
var result = context.Student.Where(x=>x.Id == model.Id);
```

In this sample, the result type is `IQueryable<T>` and didn't call database, this is just a query.

Now look this sample:

```
var result = context.Student.Where(x=>x.Id == model.Id).ToList();
```

In this sample, the result type is `T` and called database and we have data about `Student` Table.

Attention that `ToList()` Or `ToListAsync()` method always call database and execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not change signature of your `GetDataFromQuery` or you would like to save deferred execution, you can use this approach:

```
db.view.Where(m => m.ID == Search_ID).Take(1);
```

Please note that this replacement is not strictly equivalent: it will not throw even if `db.view` has no data

Comment: Meaning it will not throw an exception? What if it's inside a Try/Catch block?

Comment: @seesharp `First` will thow if source collection is empty. In same case `Take` will only return an empty collection. If your code *should* throw on empty input, you need check result length by your own